# Connect Azure SQL Server using Service Principal

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

I want to connect the Azure SQL Database using Azure service principal through Python.

Please help me

I am able to connect it through ADF using service principal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a library `Microsoft Azure Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) for Python` to connect sql server.You could get it from [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python#microsoft-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-python).

And in the wiki doc, you could find a tutorial about [connecting to Azure SQL Database](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/wiki/Connect-to-Azure-SQL-Database).

Also you could refer to this [article](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-azure-ad-service-principals-connect-sql-from-python-andrade/), it has detailed steps to connect server.

Comment: @Sumit Garg, if it helps please mark, what you did is upvote not mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time to figure this out, so I'll leave some code samples here in case it helps someone.

In my case, I had to connect to Synapse SQL Serverless from Databricks. Previously, I installed the driver "msodbcsql17" with this script:

```
%sh
#!/bin/bash
apt install unixodbc-dev
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install -y msodbcsql17
```

Then:

1. Get token:

```
from msal import ConfidentialClientApplication

creds = ConfidentialClientApplication(
    client_id='<your_client_id>', 
    authority='https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your_tenant_id>',
    client_credential= 'your_secret')

token = creds.acquire_token_for_client(scopes='https://database.windows.net//.default')
```

2. Encode token (more info here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/using-azure-ad-service-principals-connect-sql-from-python-andrade/):

```
import struct

SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN = 1256 
tokenb = bytes(token["access_token"], "UTF-8")
exptoken = b'';
for i in tokenb:
    exptoken += bytes({i});
    exptoken += bytes(1);
tokenstruct = struct.pack("=i", len(exptoken)) + exptoken;
```

3. With pyodbc, open a connection to the database using the token and execute a SQL statement:

```
import pyodbc

connString = 'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' \
             + 'SERVER=<your_server>;' \
              + 'DATABASE=<your_database>;'
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString, attrs_before = { SQL_COPT_SS_ACCESS_TOKEN:tokenstruct});

cursor = conn.cursor()
query="select name from sys.databases"
cursor.execute(query) 
row = cursor.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this tutorial:[Lesson Learned #49: Does Azure SQL Database support Azure Active Directory connections using Service Principals?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuresqldbsupport/2018/05/10/lesson-learned-49-does-azure-sql-database-support-azure-active-directory-connections-using-service-principals/)

This tutorial teaches us connect the Azure SQL Database through AAD using Azure service principle, and it provides example code in Powershell and C#.

I didn't find the example code in Python. I think this tutorial may be helpful for you, so I want to share with you.

Hope this helps.