# Connect to Azure sql in Python Using Service Principal

Tags: python, azure-sql-server, service-principal

I have a Service principal with a client id and client secret. It has permission to the Azure SQL DB. I want to use python to generate an access token and use it to authenticate to my sql server. Could someone guide me.

I am new with python and would appreciate if someone could specify if I need any supporting libraries for this to work.

Comment: You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54999904/18935775), Connect to Azure SQL using Service Principal.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use python to generate an access token.

The Azure Active Directory Authentication library for python can be used to access SQL Server in Azure.

Refer this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python#microsoft-azure-active-directory-authentication-library-adal-for-python) to know more details and how to implement the same.